# Missing lines when exporting to pdf

Tags: pdf, autocad

I'm working on some autocad drawings and it appeared that some lines are missing when I export it to PDF...
Better coverage you can see in the photos:

AutoCAD:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/MO74DeU.jpg]

PDF:

[image]

I've tried line weights, line types, colors but nothing seems to work.
Also i can't find the answer anywhere.
I hope you can help me to cope with it.

Comment: what is the printer driver you are using? Have you audited/recovered the file?

Comment: You're exporting via autocad code you've written? Please include the code. If not, wrong site.

Comment: @JoãoFonseca how can I recover the file?